# lfd - Excessive resource usage: smmsp, Process Time Exceeded

Tags: webserver

I am using amazon ec2 with csf+lfd, and always receive this kind of email:

Time:         Tue Nov 27 02:00:14 2012 +0000
Account:      smmsp
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     2722016 > 1800 (seconds)

Executable:   /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail
Command Line: sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
PID:          
Killed:       No

The time has been gone to millions seconds and counting, I wonder if this is normal.